# Invited someone as admin for the Apple Developer Program, but he can't access App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store

I've added someone as an Admin to my Apple Developer Program Membership. But if he clicks App Store Connect, he get's to the get started page instead of the main page.

Member image:

[image]

Click app store connect，jump page image:

[image]

When you click App store connect, it will go to [getting start page](https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/gettingstarted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding someone in the Developer Program doesn't give him the roles in App Store Connect. From your main account you need to go to: App Store Connect > User and Roles > Add user (follow instructions).

If this doesn't work: Have you tried just visiting [appstoreconnect.apple.com](http://appstoreconnect.apple.com) and trying to login there?